# Resizing footer columns in ng-grid

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-grid

I'm having a small issue with AngularJS and ng-grid.

I want to add a row in the footer that contains total values for each column. Using a footer template I managed to do that, so far so good.

Is there any way I can resize these columns based on the size of the grid's columns? Or at least set the row width to follow the width of the grid canvas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using CoulmnDefs and using the same widths in your footer template.

```
    $scope.gridOptions = {
    data: 'myData',
    enablePaging: true,
    showFooter: true,
    footerRowHeight:'30px',
    footerTemplate: '<div style="width: 20%; display: inline-block;">{{total1}}</div><div style="width: 60%; display: inline-block;">{{total2}}</div><div style="display: inline-block;">{{total3}}</div>',
    totalServerItems: 'totalServerItems',
    columnDefs: [{
      field: 'name',
      width: '20%'
    }, {
      field: 'allowance',
      width: '60%'
    }, {
      field: 'paid'
    }],
    pagingOptions: $scope.pagingOptions,
    filterOptions: $scope.filterOptions
    };
```

This is based on old [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/R5okPI?p=preview) I found somwhere.

If the grid gets to small this still goes bonkers. Try to set a minwidth for the grid in style.css or the for the columns in columnDefs and the footer template.

Comment: This is almost the exact thing I'm doing at the moment. The problem with this approach is that if you have a scrolling grid with many columns (which I do have), the footer doesn't scroll.

Comment: note, the total1 property shown above should probably be {{grid.appScope.total1}} if you're binding to value in your controller